# MySQL Query to return data grouped by first day of the week

Tags: mysql

i have a table of subscriptions with columns id, date, subscription_id. Now, i want a query to return the total subscriptions (count) grouped weekly by the first day of the week (sunday) like so;
Subscriptions table;

| id | client | sub_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 100 | 08/05/2022 |
| 2 | james | 101 | 09/05/2022 |
| 3 | jane | 102 | 09/05/2022 |
| 4 | anne | 103 | 11/05/2022 |
| 5 | mike | 104 | 17/05/2022 |
| 6 | james | 105 | 19/05/2022 |
| 7 | andy | 106 | 22/05/2022 |
| 8 | sol | 107 | 23/05/2022 |
| 9 | john | 108 | 23/05/2022 |
| 10 | phil | 109 | 24/05/2022 |
| 11 | gary | 110 | 25/05/2022 |
| 12 | dave | 111 | 26/05/2022 |

sample result;

| Week Starting | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 08/05/2022 | 4 |
| 15/05/2022 | 2 |
| 22/05/2022 | 6 |

I have tried this;

```
SELECT WEEK(date) AS Week, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM subscriptions 
GROUP BY Week;
```

but i get the week number instead of first day of the week as indicated in my sample result.

How can i achieve what i indicated in the sample result?

Comment: provide the subscriptions  table.

Comment: The week starting on 15/05/2022 (which ends on 21/05/2022) should have 2 counts , i.e. 17/05/2022 and 19/05/2022, not 3. I changed that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
 select ANY_VALUE(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y%U') ,"0"),'%Y%U%w')) as 'Week Starting',
 count(*) as Total
 from subscriptions 
 group by DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y%U');
```

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me of the use of `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(\`date\`,'%Y%U') ,"0"),'%Y%U%w')` to get the particular day of the week which the designated date resides in. I adjusted the names and did a bit formatting for the query. Now the OP can get the expected output. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposal, let say the table is name `subscription`

```
select count(id) `Total`, date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') `Week Starting`
from subscription where date_format(created_at, '%a') = 'Sun'
group by `Week Starting`
```

Hope it can help.